# Light emitting diode colors

Tags: diodes

Why don't they use different colors of covers for LEDs, like they do with light bulbs instead of making them form differnt semiconductors to have different colors?

In other words, why they don't make all LEDs from one semiconductor and then use LED cases with different colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the reason that LEDs are much more efficient than incandescent bulbs is that their emission spectrum is much narrower.

An incandescent bulb emits light in a broad spectrum, containing mostly IR, and small portion of visible light, which spans the entire visible spectrum. So we can remove some wavelengths from its output spectrum and be left with a narrower band, say red, or green, or blue, but only by essentially throwing away some of the bulb's output, and reducing its efficiency even further.

LEDs on the other hand, naturally only produce light with photon energy near the bandgap energy of the semiconductor material used. The output spectrum is narrow enough to appear essentially monochromatic to the human eye (although it's not as narrow as a laser's output spectrum). If we took a red LED and removed the red light from its output, there wouldn't be anything left, so you couldn't make a green light by filtering the light from a red LED. If you want a different output color from an LED, you need to find a different semiconductor material that emits that color light.

Comment: Thank you, so  when I buy different LEDs with different color cases it is just an indication of the light that it is emitting?

Comment: Yes, generally they color the plastic to match the emission color. But if you get SMT LEDs, you'll find they often have clear covers and still emit near-monochromatic light.

Answer (score 1):

Because LEDs are inherently monochromatic, whereas light bulbs emit blackbody radiation, which (at the temperatures a typical lightbulb is at) appears as white(ish) light.

If you were to put a red filter (which lets red light through) on a green LED (which only emits green light), you'd get a black LED.

Yes, you can make a white LED and then add a filter, but it's kind of annoying (white LEDs require either a mix of RGB LEDs or added phosphors that emit white(ish) light), so if we need an LED with only a single colour, that's way easier to make than a white LED.

Changing the colour of an LED is not super difficult, now that the research has been done. It's as simple as [selecting a set of inorganic materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#Colors_and_materials), which set the wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

Because LEDs create light from a fix change in the electron energy state and therefor only produce the color associated with that state change.  Colors like red are produced from a small change in the electron energy state.  Green LEDs use a larger change.  Blue still larger.  You can not add a filter to such LEDs to produce another color.

This appears to be a good source explaining how LEDs work:

http://www.okidata.co.jp/company/pdf/techtech_E04.pdf

White LEDs are actually blue or higher energy (violet or ultra violet) LEDs with a phosphorous coating.  They work similarly to the familiar florescent tube. You might have some success adding filters to white LEDs.  But this may be limited as phosphorous light sources tend to have a "choppy" spectrum.

This appears to be a nice short explanation of white LEDs:

http://www.lrc.rpi.edu/programs/nlpip/lightinganswers/led/whiteLight.asp